# Opensource projects that use gradle

Tags: java, open-source, gradle

I'm trying to find big open source projects that use Gradle as a build system. I found only Grails, Spring, Hibernate.

Are there any others?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not really answerable in its current form, or rather, seems to be better suited for a Wiki, rather than SO.

Answer (score 4):

There are many others. Some that I can recall off the top of my head:

- Many projects in the Spring IO platform (not just the Spring framework)
- Tapestry
- Groovy
- Griffon
- Qi4J
- All Netflix open-source projects

Comment: For a project that markets itself so nice and wide the list is quite short. Any more recent additions? Thanks for the answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

Some more popular projects that use Gradle: Groovy, Mockito and of course Gradle itself :)

And in my point of view the most important one: [Android SDK uses Gradle](http://www.gradleware.com/resources/tech/android) in newer versions to build apps!

Edit: But there are also big companies that use it. You can see some if you go to the [Gradleware website](http://www.gradleware.com/) and scroll to the end of the page.